# 3840x2160 resolution on external monitor possible with GeForce GTX 760M?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, 4k-resolution

I am thinking about buying an [external UHD monitor](http://www.samsung.com/de/consumer/displays/displays/uhd-monitor/LU28D590DS/EN/) for my notebook in order to have a proper resolution like 3840x2160. But I am not sure if this will work. I took a look at the [specifications](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gtx-760m/specifications)

For convenience here a copy:

[image: Display support GTX 760M]

In the [manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/N56JR/E_eManual_VER6951.pdf) of my notebook I could not find any helpful information.
Does anyone understand the information and can help me? Does this mean I have to use a DisplayPort cable if even possible? DisplayPort seems to support 3840x2160, correct?

Answer (score 1):

The manual for your laptop doesn't list a DisplayPort output. Though you might be able to still use the hdmi out, it will likely only output at [30hz rather than 60hz](http://www.overclock.net/t/1536903/gtx-760m-4k-60hz). I'm also not seeing the card on [Nvidia's list of cards that support UHD](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/4k/supported-gpus).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. 30 Hz seems to be pretty bad, I guess I will have to wait until I get a new laptop and use a Full-HD external monitor in the meantime.